# Issue with .load not refreshing div content after calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use `$( "#container" ).load("notification.html #container" );`

to refresh  `#container` after the remove button has been clicked.

At the moment, the code doesn't appear to load correctly, nothing is displayed in the div after it runs. When I manually refresh the browser does show content as expected.

Not sure what the issue is here?

```
_.each(Badges, function(item) {
    var wrapper = $('<div class ="NotifRemove"></div>');
    wrapper.append('<img id="share_button" class="images responsive-image BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
    wrapper.append('<div class="tag badgelabel" >' + item.badgename + '</div>' + '<br>');
    wrapper.append('<div class="tag awardedbylabel">' + item.AwardedBy + '</div>' + '<br>');
    wrapper.append('<div class="tag awardedbylabel">' + item.BNotify + '</div>' + '<br>');
    wrapper.append('<div class="tag senttolabel">' + item.AwardedTo + '</div>' + '<br>');
    wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="wrapper portfolio-item-thumb one-third btn_badges btn-danger_badges mrs read">' + 'Remove' + '</div>' + '<br>' + '<div class="wrapper b_seperater"></div>' + '<br>');


    $('#container').append(wrapper);

    wrapper.children('.read').click(function() {

        item.fetchedObject.set("B_Notify", "Read");




        item.fetchedObject.save(null, {
            success: function(results) {
                console.log("Read");
                $('.NotifRemove').children.hide();
                $("#container").load("notification.html #container");

            },
            error: function(contact, error) {
                // The save failed.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });


    });

});
```

fiddle created here http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/un761pc2/14/

Comment: *" shows the relevant content."* - What is relevant content..? "*At the moment, using the both all"* - What do you mean *both*..? BTW please format the code properly... http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: `notification.html` is a separate HTML file in the root folder having an element with `id` " container", and every time you `load()` you expect to see the very same content that was loaded previously. Correct..?

Comment: Basically yes, the user is clicking the "remove" button which then turns a flag in the database to "read" by refreshing the div, that particular would then no longer show. Hope that helps?

Comment: Is `notification.html` a separate document or is it the one you're working with..? `load()` will always load the **same** static content which is inside `notification.html`. Or is that file generated by a server side script such as `php`..?

Comment: @TJ yes notification is a separate document. notification.html has the div #container the content for that is generated from notification.js I'm using parse.com and the javaScript SDK to create a query that returns the data

Comment: The load method will not execute the scripts in `notification.html` as far as I know, it'll just fetch the raw html. So if `load()` isn't executing your `notification.js`, will you get the expected data..?

Comment: So in conclusion I need to look at approaching this in a different manner?